# How to Remove empty line or space on pre in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

The Output of the code are having too many blank space or empty line. How to remove those. I want the line-height to be equal.

To Explain more the detail, I attached the whole code below.

```js
function clicked() {
  document.getElementById("data").innerHTML =
    "Fethching Score and Ranking <br>loading...";

  var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  var url = document.getElementById("url").value;
  if (url == "") {
    alert("Please enter URL");
    return;
  }
  var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhr.open(
    "GET",
    "https://www.googleapis.com/pagespeedonline/v1/runPagespeed?screenshot=false&strategy=mobile&url=" +
      encodeURIComponent(url)
  );
  
  xhr.onload = function() {
    document.getElementById("data").innerHTML = xhr.responseText.replace(/[!@#$^&%*"()+=[\]\{}|<>?,\\-]/g,'');;
 };
  xhr.send();
}
```

```css
#data{white-space: pre-line;}
```

```html
<input type="text" placeholder="Enter URL with http:// or https://" id="url" class="form-control"/>
<p class="help-block">with <code>http</code> or <code>https</code></p>
<input type="button" value=" ENTER" onclick="clicked();" class="btn btn-success"/>

<pre id="data"></pre>
```

Comment: What url are we supposed to enter to see the data with too much blank space?

Comment: http://google.com or any website

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just remove the blank lines (assuming that "blank" also means lines with only spaces/tabs). You can chain multiple `.replace`s:

```
document.getElementById("data").innerHTML = xhr.responseText
                                               .replace(/[!@#$^&%*"()+=[\]\{}|<>?,\\-]/g,'')
      /* this is the added part: */            .replace(/^\s*[\r\n]/gm, '');
```

The `^\s*[\r\n]` regex basically means "any number (incl. 0) of whitespace characters and end-of-line". Flags are for [`g`lobal and `m`multiline](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp#Parameters).